# How do I collect an end date when creating a Date field in code?

Tags: entities, nodes

This is my field definition:

```
'ms_date' => array(
            'field_name' => 'ms_date',
            'type' => 'datetime',
            'cardinality' => 1,
            'settings' => array(
                'cache_count' => '4',
                'cache_enabled' => 0,
                'granularity' => array(
                    'day' => 'day',
                    'hour' => 'hour',
                    'minute' => 'minute',
                    'month' => 'month',
                    'second' => 'second',
                    'year' => 'year',
                ),
                'timezone_db' => 'UTC',
                'todate' => '',
                'tz_handling' => 'site',
            ),
        ),
```

and the instance definition:

```
 'ms_date' => array(
        'field_name' => 'ms_date',
        'entity_type' => 'node',
        'bundle' => 'ms_core',
        'label' => $t('date'),
        'widget' => array(
            'active' => 1,
            'module' => 'date',
            'settings' => array(
                'increment' => 15,
                'input_format' => 'm/d/Y - H:i:s',
                'input_format_custom' => '',
                'label_position' => 'above',
                'text_parts' => array(),
                'year_range' => '-3:+3',
            ),
            'type' => 'date_text',
            'weight' => '1',
        ),
        'settings' => array(
            'cache_count' => '4',
            'cache_enabled' => 0,
            'granularity' => array(
                'day' => 'day',
                'hour' => 'hour',
                'minute' => 'minute',
                'month' => 'month',
                'second' => 'second',
                'year' => 'year',
            ),
            'timezone_db' => 'UTC',
            'todate' => '',
            'tz_handling' => 'site',
        ),
    ),
```

I'm using these structures with [field_create_field](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.crud.inc/function/field_create_field/7) and [field_create_instance](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.crud.inc/function/field_create_instance/7) respectively.

Currently the "Collect an end date" textfield is missing when I create this field. How do I enable it?

Answer (score 3):

You just need to set the `todate` under the `settings` array, I believe the 2 options available are

```
'todate' => 'optional',
```

and

```
'todate' => 'required',
```